# Wicket trigger request after another request

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, wicket

I try my best to describe my situation. 
My wicket site contains list wicket component, where every list element has another list. Each element in lowest level list has ajax wicket link to download some file. All this works fine. I used to this AjaxBehaviour. Method startDownload of this behaviour is invoked within link onClick method.

```
 public void startDownload(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    target.appendJavaScript("window.location.href='" + getCallbackUrl() +"'");
  }
```

Method onRequest of this behaviour is:

```
@Override
  public void onRequest() {
    IRequestHandler fileTarget = new IRequestHandler() {

      @Override
      public void respond(IRequestCycle requestCycle) {
        if (null != file) {
          try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            WebResponse resp = (WebResponse) requestCycle.getResponse();
            resp.setAttachmentHeader(fileName);
            String contentType = FileUtils.getFileType(fileName);
            if (contentType != null) {
              resp.setContentType(contentType);
            }
            resp.setHeader("Pragma", "anytextexeptno-cache");
            resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");

            Streams.copy(inputStream, requestCycle.getResponse().getOutputStream());
          } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
          }
        }
      }
```

Now i need to reload model and refresh some components in the page after download file action. I tried to add entire page to the AjaxRequestTarget in method onclick, after code invoked startDownload method. Reload page works fine but window with file to download doesn`t show.

I think that i have to do reload page in other, separate request (maybe i'm mistaken? ), because in this request i call 'window.location.href=....', but i don`t know how i can to enforce second request to reload page.

Does have someone some ideas what I do wrong ? And how can I resolve my problem  ?

Comment: There's no point in first doing an Ajax request and then reloading the complete page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my implementation is simmilar to this from cwiki.apache.org website. In onRequest method i used         getComponent().getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(handler), and despite of this doesn`t work.

Is possible that reason of this is component, which cause request is added to target (because i add to target entire page and component - ajaxLink in this example, is child of this page)

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need something like this:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow